# How to handle cross domain logic in Domain Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am new in DDD and I am trying to use it in my Go REST API project. I am quite confuse about how to handle the situation when there are logic which may cross the domain.

Let say I have the following folder structure where I have two domains (Customer and Order):

```
+.
-- Customer
   +-- service
       +-- http
   +-- usecase
   +-- repository
-- Order
   +-- service
       +-- http
   +-- usecase
   +-- repository
```

In general speaking, assume there is an endpoint in the `Order` domain that would provide a create order feature, then the http service should act as a router and call the corresponding `usecase` to handle the logic by adding order data to the `repository` (database).

How about if I would like to add a new logic that customer will get certain `reward points` when they create an order. Assume there is a `CreateOrder` function in the usecase to create a new order into the database, but how should I interactive with the `Customer` domain so that I could add `reward points` to a customer?

I am thinking of calling the Customer usecase function from the Order usecase function but I am not sure whether it will trigger the `circular import` issue.

Answer (score 4):

In an event-driven architecture you would use messaging to decouple your systems.

You reward system could, for instance, subscribe to the `CustomerActivatedEvent` and register a new customer to track rewards for.  In addition the reward bounded context could subscribe to the `OrderShippedEvent` and handle the appropriate reward processing.

In this way you `Customers` and `Ordering` BCs don't even know about each other but the `Rewards` BC can happily reward the various customers.